# Why does Perl 6's Map give me a value in one case and a list in another?

Tags: raku

I'm playing with [Map](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Map) and I get a result I don't understand.

First, I construct the [Map](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Map). No big whoop:

```
> my $m = Map.new: '1' => :1st, '2' => :2nd;
Map.new(("1" => :st(1),"2" => :nd(2)))
```

I access a single element by the literal key and get back a Pair:

```
> $m<1>.^name
Pair
> $m<<1>>.^name
Pair
```

That's all fine.

If I try it with the key in a variable, I get back a [List](https://docs.perl6.org/type/List) instead:

```
> my $n = 1
1
> $m<<$n>>.^name
List
```

That list has the right value, but why do I get a [List](https://docs.perl6.org/type/List) in that case and not the `$m<<1>>` case?

And, once I have the list, I seem unable to chain another subscript to it:

```
> $m<<$n>>.[0]
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling:
Unable to parse quote-words subscript; couldn't find right double-angle quote
at line 2
```

Comment: another ((un)related?) inconsistency: `say <<1>>.^name # IntStr` vs `my $n = 1; say <<$n>>.^name # Slip` vs `say <<1 2>>.^name # List`

Comment: After thinking about this some more and talking to the person who showed me the problem, I think the `$m<<1>>` should return a List too. Then things would make sense. If it's a list of one IntStr, that's fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you access an associative value like this, the compiler can tell that it need only ever return one value.

```perl6
$m<  1  >
$m<< 1 >>
```

In Perl 6, a singular value will in many cases behave just like a list of one value.

```perl6
42.elems == 1 # True
42.[0] =:= 42 # True
```

---

In the following case, the compiler can't immediately tell that it will only produce one value:

```perl6
my $n = 1;
$m<< $n >>;
```

As it could produce 2 values:

```perl6
my $o = '1 2';
$m<< $o >>;
```

If you want the string to be a single key, you have to use quotation marks.

```perl6
$m<< "$o" >>
```

Or use the more appropriate `{}`

```perl6
$m{ $n }
```

---

The `$m<1>` is just a combination of two features.

1. Quotewords: ( `qw<>` and `qqww<<>>` )

   ```perl6
   <   a  b  c   > eqv ("a", "b", "c")
   <  "a  b" c   > eqv (｢"a｣, ｢b"｣, "c") # three strings

   <<  a  b  c  >> eqv ("a", "b", "c")
   << "a  b" c  >> eqv ("a  b", "c")    # two strings
   ```
2. Associative indexing:

   ```perl6
   %h<   a  b  c  > eqv %h{ <   a  b  c  > }
   %h<< "a  b" c >> eqv %h{ << "a  b" c >> }
   ```

---

Also I now get back different values.

```perl6
$m<   1  >.WHAT =:= Pair
$m<<  1 >>.WHAT =:= Pair
$m<< $n >>.WHAT =:= Pair # different

$m<< $o >>.WHAT =:= List
```

---

The reason `$m<<$n>>.[0]` doesn't work is the compiler thinks you are using a hyper postfix `>>.[0]`.

There are a couple ways of working around that.

1. Actually using a hyper postfix

   ```perl6
   $m<<$n>>>>.[0]
   $m<<$n>>».[0]
   ```
2. Use an unspace. (can never be inside of an operator so will split them up)

   ```perl6
   $m<<$n>>\.[0]
   $m<<$n>>\     .[0]
   ```

I think this is a bug, as it doesn't make much sense to be matching a hyper postfix inside of a quotewords statement.
(It doesn't affect `$m<<1>>.elems`)

Comment: That’s a good explanation of reality. I still don’t like the part where the compiler decides this rather than a consequence of normal functioning of features. That’s why I’m often surprised with these things.